# Get a list of files with full path from different directories

Tags: python, list, path, glob

I have a list of directory paths and would like to create a combined list of files in these directories incl. full path name.
I am iterating through the list of directories using glob.glob() to get the files with full path name and then append it to an output list but for some reason I end up with a list of lists instead a single list containing the files

```
fileli = []

for item in sourceli:
    file = glob.glob(item + '/****-****-**-**.txt')
    fileli.append(file)
```

this returns a list of e.g. 3 lists if I have three directories, like this
[[filedir1.txt],[filedir2.txt],[filedir3.txt]]

Another approach I tried:

```
fileli.append([glob.glob(item + '/****-****-**-**.txt') for item in sourceli])
```

but it returns a list in a list in a list like this
[[[filedir1.txt, filedir2.txt, filedir3.txt]]]

Would appreciate if someone could explain (in rather simple terms, beginner here) why I end up with the results I get for each approach and how to get a single list of files like this [filedir1.txt, filedir2.txt, filedir3.txt].

Thanks a lot!

Update:
Figured out what's happening with my code. Wasn't aware that `file = glob.glob(item + '/****-****-**-**.txt')` will return a list and therefore iterating through my list of directories will get me a list that's then appended to the list of files. Adding another for-loop now gives me the result I was looking for.

```
for item in sourceli:
    print(item)
    files = glob.glob(path + '/****-****-**-**.txt')
    for file in files:
        fileli.append(file)
```

Comment: Do you need `os.listdir()`?

Comment: `fileli.extend(file)`

Comment: I believe the approach below is a simpler solution to your question as it lists all of the txt files in all directories with the full path and appends them to a single list. I don't think you need multiple lists.